# Regex for wildcard connected to string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to match a string in which the first wildcard is not seperated from the rest of the string by a space character.

```
(?<=<br> ).*?【.*?】 \(.*?\)<br>
```

For instance, of the following example...

```
<br> 一を知って二を知らず　see only one side of a matter; have only a narrow understanding.<br> いつ１【一】 (itsu)<br>
```

... only this should be matched:

```
いつ１【一】 (itsu)<br>
```

Currently my regex matches everything after the first `<br>`  , irregardless of distance to the brackets `【`. (Keep in mind the brackets are one character.)

How do you convey that the wildcard should be 'joined' with the rest of the string?

Comment: Please add some details on why you expect this match.

Comment: What do you mean by "wildcard". Note that wildcards and regexes are different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly whay you need, but based on your example pattern and example output you likely want this:

```
(?<=<br> )[^<]*?【[^】]*】 \([^\)]*\)<br>
```

Match:

```
いつ１【一】 (itsu)<br>
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=<br> )` - positive lookbehind
- `[^<]*?` - non-greedy scan over all non-`<` chars
- `【[^】]*】` - scan over `【` ... `】`
- - space char
- `\([^\)]*\)` - scan over `(` ... `)`
- `<br>` - match `<br>`